# How to detect same user when they submit two webforms?

Tags: 7, webforms

User A submit a newsletter form and come to thank you page. At the thank you page there is another general comment form.

Here is my question: How to detect both of them are belong to User A?

Reason: So that I can extract both information together from database.

Comment: What are you using to submit a newsletter ?

Comment: Both of them are webform. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another less obvious solution if using the rules module already is https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_session_vars

Set the variable when the first form is submitted and check for it when the second is submitted. The use rules to do whatever is needed.

Your own prepopulate solution is perfectly fine however. This one just stops someone from hacking the url.

Answer (score 0):

I find out a solution. Get URL and pass it to webform's hidden field. When User Submitted a form and redirect to thank you page, in the URL will show unquie sid. With this sid, I can know they the forms submit by same person.

I wonder is there any better solution.